# Saving a string with \x01 characters to disk

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

I need to write to disk a string of characters that includes `chr(1)` characters to separate fields. Eventually I need to open this file in Pandas with `read_csv`()` (hopefully using the C-parser, although this is somewhat relevant now).

My data is stored in memory as bytes:

```
> data?
Type:        bytes
String form: b'foo\x01302.0\x011407339259000\nbar\x01206.0\x011407339259230\n < .. >
```

In the example above, the first two rows would be:

```
foo 102.0 1407339259000 
bar 206.0 1407339259230
```

How can I save this stream of bytes in Python 3 so that I can later open it in Pandas with:

```
 read_csv('foo.csv',sep='\x01')
```

?

I tried with:

```
  with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(data.decode(encoding='ascii'))
```

with no luck. If I later try to open the file with:

```
pd.read_csv('my_file', sep='\x01')
```

I get a Dataframe with several rows and 1 column (i.e. no field splitting).

## Update

```
with open('my_file', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(data)
```

and then:

```
pd.read_csv('my_file', sep='\x01')
```

I also get a Dataframe with several rows and 1 column (i.e. no field splitting).

Comment: What do you think about the codecs package? So something like this for example: csvreader = csv.reader(codecs.open("some.csv", "r", "cp1252"))

Comment: What does "with no luck" mean? What happened?

Comment: @abarnert I just updated the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have binary characters/bytes you need write, you also need to open with binary mode, i.e. `open('foo.csv', 'wb')`, and then just write data (as it is already of type `bytes`).

```
# assuming isinstance(data, bytes) is True
with open('foo.csv', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Assuming the file was written correctly, you should be able to read it like so.  Anyway, for your sake I now got pandas installed, and this is what happens if I tried to do what you want to do:

```
>>> with open('dummy.csv', 'wb') as f:
...     f.write(b'foo\x01302.0\x011407339259000\nbar\x01206.0\x011407339259230\n')
... 
48
>>> import pandas
>>> foo = pandas.read_csv('dummy.csv', sep='\x01')
>>> foo.keys()
Index(['foo', '302.0', '1407339259000'], dtype='object')
>>> foo.values
array([['bar', 206.0, 1407339259230]], dtype=object)
```

Note that all values are what you would have expected.

Comment: Right - you have a bytestream already, and that's what goes to your file. No need to mess around with encodings, you know the exact bytes you want to write.

Comment: metatoaster and @PeterDeGlopper. This isn't working for me. See the updates on my post.

Comment: @user815423426 answer updated with an actual example to show that what I've done earlier would have given you the expected results.